# Microsoft Teams Single Sign On on a custom tab

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams

we developed a very simple Tab app that will bring out application to Teams. We wanted to use Single Sign On so not to require the user to register with our app but to authenticate her/him immediately by taking the name and the email from the requested token. We followed thoroughly this Doc page [Single Sign-On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso) and all works well in the account that the app was developed. But when we try to install on another account, we couldn't get the token. `microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken(authTokenRequest)` returns error that the app is not authorized. The strange thing is that no consent screen is presented to the user so I really don't know how to let the user authorize the app. I thought this is part of the flow. Any ideas? Thank you.

Please note that the app is allowed to work in "Accounts in any organizational directory".

[image]

Comment: Could you please confirm if your app is allowed to work in "Accounts in any organisational directory"? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYcIR.png

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT, yes, I do. Thank you very much for looking into this.

Comment: Can you try installing this sample [manifest](https://github.com/ydogandjiev/taskmeow/blob/master/manifest/sso/taskmeow-sso.zip) for SSO and see if that works in that account?

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT Hello, as far as I understand this app uses Azure Authentication Flow. I really would like to use the Single Sign On flow for Teams as described in this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso

Comment: The sample i shared uses SSO only. Please try install it and see if that works.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT I did install it and I see "Sign In" button on the "My tasks" tab. But I don't think this is the SSO flow because in this flow the Teams is asking for consent on the behalf of the app.

Comment: You would need to provide a one time consent to use your app. SSO does not ask for user's login credentials and picks up the details from the Teams sign-in. But you still need to provide a one-time consent to your app.